# Update paneel blocks execution of some error messages

Tags: asp.net, mysql, vb.net

I ave an asp page with 1 update panels with 2 panels which are controlled by 2 buttons if you click in first button first panel appears and second becomes hidden and if you click second button the same thing happens for the second panel. It's working ok and no problem about that.

The problem begins in the second panel where I have another update panel which is in charge of printing error messages. The messages which just check the length of input are working ok, but those messages which involve querying the database to check the validity of id are not being printed .

I thought the querying are the problem and I've tried them in a separated page without update panels and they are working ok. The problem lays somewhere with Update panels. And I really can't understand where. I would be most grateful if you can help me.

This is front end code(i omit some insignificant details):

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="[Input your Id?]"  />
<asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="[Aditional info]"  />
  .....
 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
  <ContentTemplate>
 < asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
 some code here

 </asp:Panel>

 <asp:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server">

<b>*ID Number:&nbsp;&nbsp;</b> 
<asp:TextBox ID="IdNo" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox><font size='2'>
  <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" class="errorMess" ErrorMessage="Letters are not Allowed!!" ControlToValidate="IdNumb" ValidationExpression="\d+"
    runat="server" />
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel3" runat="server">
   <ContentTemplate>
   <asp:Label ID="errorEm"  class="errorMess" runat="server" Text="Please fill in the required fields"></asp:Label>
   <asp:Label ID="errorLenght"  class="errorMess" runat="server" Text="Id is too long!!!"></asp:Label>
   <asp:Label ID="errorUser"  class="errorMess" runat="server" Text="Id is not valid!!!"></asp:Label>
   </ContentTemplate>
   <Triggers>
   <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Button5" EventName="Click" />
   </Triggers>
   </asp:UpdatePanel> 
   <asp:Button ID="Button5" runat="server" Text="Generate" /></td></tr>

   </asp:Panel>
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
   <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Button1" EventName="Click" />
   </Triggers>
   </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

and this is backend VB code:

```
 Protected Sub Button5_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles  Button5.Click
If IdNo.Text = "" Then
    Panel1.Visible = False
    Panel2.Visible = True
    errorEm.Visible = True
ElseIf IdNo.Text.Length > 9 Then
    Panel1.Visible = False
    Panel2.Visible = True
    errorLenght.Visible = True
Else

    Try 'everything that comes here does not work'
        myconn.Open()
        Dim stquery As String = "SELECT * from account WHERE user_id= @id"
        Dim smd = New MySqlCommand(stquery, myconn)
        smd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", Convert.ToInt32(IdNo.Text))
        Dim myreader = smd.ExecuteReader()
        If Not myreader.HasRows Then
            Panel1.Visible = False
            Panel2.Visible = True
            errorUser.Visible = True
            myconn.Close()
            Return
        Else

            Panel1.Visible = False
            Panel2.Visible = True
            myreader.Read()
            Dim ErrorMessage As String = "alert('User has been found');"
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "ErrorAlert", ErrorMessage, True)


            myconn.Close()
        End If
        myconn.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        Dim ErrorMessage As String = "alert('" & ex.Message.ToString() & "');"
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "ErrorAlert", ErrorMessage, True)
        myconn.Close()
    End Try
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you know that `RegularExpressionValidator` can be used to validate length of input so you don't have to check it in code-behind manually? Just set `ValidationExpression="^\d{5,9}$"` which means input must be digits only with length of between 5 to 9 chars.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to execute script from inside of Update panel - don't use

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript
```

Use

```
ClientScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript
```

instead.

Ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.registerstartupscript.aspx